# Which time does the `crontab` listen to? Local, Universal or RTC time?

Tags: linux, cron

Following is the result of the command, `timedatectl`, which lists different "types" of time.

- Local time
- Universal time
- RTC time

Which time do the `crontab` listen to as my cron-job is not running.

```
$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Thu 2019-12-26 15:43:38 IST
                  Universal time: Thu 2019-12-26 10:13:38 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2019-12-26 10:13:39
                       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: should be running at the local timezone hours. Let us know the crontab entry if it still has problem

Comment: Sometimes I forget crontab wants a military time format, like 9pm is 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quoted in crontab manual

> "The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local
>   time zone, where the daemon is running."

So your cronjob will be running according to your local timezone i.e. Local time.

You can read more here [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Comment: You're right, but it is not working...

Comment: `01 * * * * echo "\`date\`" >> /home/ubuntu/test.log` even this is not running...

Comment: Run the crontab with your user. Type the following command
`crontab -u username -e`  this will give permission to your user for execution to your user. or you can also specify the username in the cronjob like this `2 5 * * * username /path/to/your/script.sh`

Comment: I might have some insight as to what caused the confusion of the OP. I had the default GMT as my timezone. I changed it with ` timedatectl` to the appropriate timezone but my crontab job would still not get picked up at the expected minute/hour. A reboot later (perhaps restarting then cron service would have sufficed) and my job was picked up as expected.